# $P(X+Y=k | Y=y) $ to $ P(X=k-y)$

Tags: probability

> Let $ X ∼ Geom (p)$ and $Y ∼ U (0, 1, . . . , n)$ be random variables. Find the probability distribution of $Z = X + Y$ .

## Don't give me the solution to the question above.

What I did so far:

$$ P(X+Y=k) $$
$$ = \sum_{y=0}^{n} P(X+Y=k | Y=y)*P(Y=y) $$

Now, my only question is, why I'm allowed to conclude the following:
$$ = \sum_{y=0}^{n} P(X=k-y)*P(Y=y) $$

- Logically it seems correct but then I can conclude the following as well: $P(X+Y=k \cap Y=y) $ to $ P(X=k-y)$. Is it correct also?

Comment: If you already know that $Y = y$ then $X+Y = k \iff X = k-y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $$P(X+Y=k)=\sum_{\{(x,y)|x+y=k\}} P(X=x \cap Y=y)$$
You write one of them in terms of $k$ and another one:
$$P(X+Y=k)=\sum_{y=0}^{n} P(X=k-y \cap Y=y)$$
**If they're independent**, $$P(X+Y=k)=\sum_{y=0}^{n} P(X=k-y)P(Y=y)$$
which is exactly what you want to have. **If not**,$$\sum_{y=0}^{n} P(X=k-y \cap Y=y)=\sum_{y=0}^{n} P(X=k-y | Y=y)P(Y=y)$$ and that's it. This step comes from conditioning on $Y$ (and total probability if you wish).

---

However, consider what you propose:$$P(X+Y=k)=\sum_{y=0}^{n}P(X+Y=k \cap Y=y)=\sum_{y=0}^{n}P(X=k-y)$$
The event $\{X+Y=k \cap Y=y\}$ implies $\{X=k-y\} \cap \{Y=y\}$. The reason you can't leave $\{Y=y\}$ is that you're kind of considering two events in one space. $y$ gives you only the iterator if you drop it (which doesn't have any meaning in this case).

Another way to see this is by conditional probability. When considering $P(X=k-y | Y=y)$, you know that $\{Y=y\}$ has already happened. *You're taking some information away in your proposition*:

*Independent case*: $P(X+Y=k \cap Y=y)=P(X+Y=k)P(Y=y)$. Since you're summing over $y$, $P(X+Y=k \cap Y=y)=P(X=k-y)P(Y=y)$ for each $y$.

*Dependent case*: $P(X+Y=k \cap Y=y)=P(X+Y=k|Y=y)P(Y=y)=P(X=k-y|Y=y)P(Y=y)$.

In either way, $P(X+Y=k \cap Y=y)\neq P(X=k-y)$.

Comment: The question does not explicitly indicate that $X$ and $Y$ independent.

Comment: Oh, I miss this. The general case is by doing $$P(X+Y=k)=\sum_{y=0}^{n} P(X=k-y | Y=y)P(Y=y)$$, then stop here. If you have two independent r.v.'s, knowing $Y=y$ has no effect on $P(X=k-y | Y=y)$. You then only have the product $P(X=k-y)P(Y=y)$.

Comment: See if my edits could clear up your confusions.

Comment: Thanks for editing! Does $\sum_{y=0}^{n} P(X=k-y \cap Y=y)$ equal to $\sum_{y=0}^{n} P(X+Y=k \cap Y=y)$ ?

Comment: Yes, because you "specify" the event $Y=y$ on the same line.

Comment: Thanks! I also need a clue - Can I prove that $X$ and $Y$ are independent? I don't know how to go on from $$\sum_{y=0}^{n} P(X=k-y \cap Y=y)=\sum_{y=0}^{n} P(X=k-y | Y=y)P(Y=y)$$

Comment: If $X$ and $Y$ are independent, $P(X\cap Y)=P(X)P(Y)$ (you kind of do this all the time).$$\sum_{y=0}^{n} P(X=k-y \cap Y=y)=\sum_{y=0}^{n} P(X=k-y | Y=y)P(Y=y)$$ is originally $P(X+Y=k)$. However if you have some extra numbers/information, implying $P(X=k-y | Y=y)=P(X=k-y)$, you can conclude $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: I have nothing more then what I provided already in the question. Does it mean that this question is unsolvable?

Comment: No, you make $P(X+Y=k) = \sum_{y=0}^{n} P(X=k-y | Y=y)P(Y=y)$, which is *always* true. You drop the "given" information part if you find $X$ and $Y$ are independent.